# How to match a string until a certain pattern (Python 3.8)

Tags: regex, python-3.x, timestamp

I got a small problem with my regex.

I want to pare a p-list file to get a unix (10 digis) timestamp plus **everything until a certain pattern** after the timestamp. My current pattern looks like that:

```
,\s*(\d{10}),\s*'(?=.[',])
```

I want to match the timestamp and **everything between the timestamp and the certain pattern** `',`.

This is a snipped of the string, out of the p-list:

```
'$class': UID(23)}, 1572871204, 'I need this one', {'dictionary': UID(34)
```

I want to get:

```
1573078965, 'I need this one'
```

It would be ideal if I get the **timestamp as a submatch and the string as another submatch**.

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Between the positive lookahead, you could add another capturing group matching not a comma or `'` using a negated character class `([^,']+)`.

But as you are matching the comma before as well, you can omit the lookahead and match the comma afterwards instead.

For example

```
,\s*(\d{10}),\s*'([^,']+)[',]
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/Upue43/1)